# Ms Excel - VBA Code/Macro to Autofill Columns

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me with VBA code in Excel to fill a columns by specific text.
In column there are 1000 rows and after every 200 or 300 rows the text change.I want to replicate the text to every row and when the text change the next text should be replicated and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could just have `=A1` in A2, and then fill down. Then you could overwrite this with whatever text you want to appear in the below cells.

Comment: Post example data...

Comment: So, using my suggestion above, simply type "Product" in A101, and then `=A101` will refer to this, `=A102` will refer to that, and so forth. No VBA required.

Comment: @0m3r , see image for example data, thank you.

Comment: @jsheeran, i have thousands of records (3000x12) and more to come , it's not possible to refer each , i require vba to autofill text based on condition, thank you in advance.

Comment: like in the image above, rows after energy should be fill with text energy and when row pow come/text change it should autofill with that text and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this...

Select the whole column A, press Ctrl+G and click on Special --> select Blanks --> Click OK --> from your keyboard type = and press up arrow key and press Ctrl+Enter (i.e. hold down the Ctrl key and hit Enter) and then copy the column A and paste it back as Values only.

Or you can simply run the following macro which will perform all the steps written above...

```
Sub Autofill()
Dim lr As Long
lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
On Error Resume Next
Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
Range("A2:A" & lr).Value = Range("A2:A" & lr).Value
End Sub
```

If you have multiple columns to autofil, you can replace the Range("A2:A" & lr) with your actual range like Range("A2:Z" & lr) where Z is the last column used on the sheet for an example.

Comment: wow @sktneer , it works , thank you sooo much , just one question as i am new in this , how to run a macro if i want to go for code , can you let me know about it.thank you,it's amazing :)

Comment: To implement the code, open your workbook --> Press Alt+F11 to open VB Editor --> on VB Editor --> Insert --> Module and paste the code into the opened code window --> Close VB editor and save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook. To run the code, press Alt+F8 to open Macro Window, select the macro Autofill from the list and click on Run.

Comment: wow thank you :) it work just it have one problem.as you can see in image after row 1 ,one cell is empty and after row 2 ,two cells are empty, it's copying row 1 and row 2 in that .. is there a way that it doesn't copy row 1 and 2 row ?

Comment: You're welcome ABC! In Range("A2:A" & lr) 2 is the row where autofill will start from. If you want to skip rows 1 and 2, replace the range Range("A2:A" & lr) with Range("A3:A" & lr)

Comment: thank you so much , you made my day , thank you again :)